# Use Kafka to stream files with metadata?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka

i want to ask, if someone has experience with producing and consuming files in Kafka.

.NET C# should be the language.

We are working on a concept which takes files (max 100mb) from several sources and and write multiple comsumers and react on different types, for example email or physical file, enriched with metadata.

I tried to play a little bit with it.

The best case would be to use the schema registry.

I set up a docker-compose file to testing purposes which looks like this:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.2
    hostname: zoo1
    container_name: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zoo1:2888:3888

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.2
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9999:9999"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092,DOCKER://host.docker.internal:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9001
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: ${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}
      KAFKA_AUTHORIZER_CLASS_NAME: kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
      KAFKA_ALLOW_EVERYONE_IF_NO_ACL_FOUND: "true"
    depends_on:
      - zoo1

  kafka-schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.2
    hostname: kafka-schema-registry
    container_name: kafka-schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: kafka-schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1

  
  kafka-rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:7.3.2
    hostname: kafka-rest-proxy
    container_name: kafka-rest-proxy
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      # KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo1:2181
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8082/
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://kafka-schema-registry:8081/
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: kafka-rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19092
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1
      - kafka-schema-registry

  
  kafka-connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:7.3.2
    hostname: kafka-connect
    container_name: kafka-connect
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "kafka1:19092"
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://kafka-schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://kafka-schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-connect"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: "INFO"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: "1"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components'
    volumes:
      - ./connectors:/etc/kafka-connect/jars/
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1
      - kafka-schema-registry
      - kafka-rest-proxy
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - |
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-mysql:latest
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.4.0
        /etc/confluent/docker/run

  
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:7.3.2
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:19092
      KSQL_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8088/
      KSQL_KSQL_SERVICE_ID: ksqldb-server_
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      - kafka1

  postgresql:
    extends:
      service: postgresql
      file: conduktor.yml 
            
  conduktor-platform:
    extends:
      service: conduktor-platform
      file: conduktor.yml

volumes:
  pg_data: {}
  conduktor_data: {}
```

Here is a dumb .Net Core API to produce some messages:
KafkaProducerController.cs

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/kafka")]
    public class KafkaProducerController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly KafkaDependentProducer<Null, string> messageProducer;
        private readonly KafkaDependentProducer<Null, FileData> iDokProducer;
        private string topic;
        private string iDokTopic;
        private readonly ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
            MessageMaxBytes = 10000000
        };

        public KafkaProducerController(KafkaDependentProducer<Null, string> messageProducer, KafkaDependentProducer<Null, FileData> iDokProducer, IConfiguration config)
        {
            this.topic = config.GetValue<string>("Kafka:MessageTopic");
            this.iDokTopic = config.GetValue<string>("Kafka:iDokTopic");
            this.messageProducer = messageProducer;
            this.iDokProducer = iDokProducer;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostAsync([FromQuery] string message)
        {
            var kafkaMessage = new Message<Null, string> { Value = message };
            await this.messageProducer.ProduceAsync(topic, kafkaMessage);
            return Ok();
            //return Created(string.Empty, SendToKafka("gtm-test", kafkaMessage));
        }

        [HttpPost("upload")]
        //[Route("file")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostFileAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file == null || file.Length <= 0)
            {
                return BadRequest("No file uploaded.");
            }


            var kafkaMessage = new Message<Null, FileData> { Value = { formFile = file, Info1 = "Test", Info2 = "Test2" } };


            await this.iDokProducer.ProduceAsync(iDokTopic, kafkaMessage);
            return Ok();
    }
}
```

KafkaDepedentProducer.cs:

```
public class KafkaDependentProducer<K, V>
    {
        IProducer<K, V> kafkaHandle;

        public KafkaDependentProducer(KafkaClientHandle handle, ISerializer<V> serializer = null)
        {
            if (serializer == null)
            {
                kafkaHandle = new DependentProducerBuilder<K, V>(handle.Handle).Build();
            }
            else
            {
                kafkaHandle = new DependentProducerBuilder<K, V>(handle.Handle)
                    .SetValueSerializer(serializer)
                    .Build();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Asychronously produce a message and expose delivery information
        ///     via the returned Task. Use this method of producing if you would
        ///     like to await the result before flow of execution continues.
        /// <summary>
        public Task ProduceAsync(string topic, Message<K, V> message)
            => this.kafkaHandle.ProduceAsync(topic, message);

        /// <summary>
        ///     Asynchronously produce a message and expose delivery information
        ///     via the provided callback function. Use this method of producing
        ///     if you would like flow of execution to continue immediately, and
        ///     handle delivery information out-of-band.
        /// </summary>
        public void Produce(string topic, Message<K, V> message, Action<DeliveryReport<K, V>> deliveryHandler = null)
            => this.kafkaHandle.Produce(topic, message, deliveryHandler);

        public void Flush(TimeSpan timeout)
            => this.kafkaHandle.Flush(timeout);
    }
```

And the consumer:

Program.cs

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Demo for using Kafka APIs");

            Consume("gtm-test");
        }
        static void Consume(string topic)
        {
            var conf = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = "st_consumer_group",
                BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) =>
            {
                e.Cancel = true; // prevent the process from terminating.
                cts.Cancel();
            };

            using (var builder = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore,FileData>(conf)
                .SetValueDeserializer(new JsonDeserializer<FileData>().AsSyncOverAsync())
                .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
                .Build())
            {
                builder.Subscribe(new List<string>() { "gtm-test", "gtm-test-file"});
                var cancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var consumer = builder.Consume(cancelToken.Token);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Message: {consumer.Message.Value} received from {consumer.TopicPartitionOffset}, Topic: {consumer.Topic}");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    builder.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka is not made to transfer large files. You would need to tune a lot the brokers (if even possible, you will face many limitations) and the applications producing/consuming these data (tons of thresholds, buffers, and timeouts to change)

Instead, you should pick one of these two options:

- Send your files chunk by chunk into the topic to align with Kafka best practices (small records) and rebuild the file on the consumer time (re-assembling the chunks).
- Use the *Claim-Check pattern* (as explained by OneCricketeer). Your producer sends a simple reference to a file stored somewhere else (S3) in the topic, the consumer reads it and fetches this reference from a Cold storage like S3.  You would have to share some secrets for your applications to access S3.

(disclaimer: my company wrote about this more in-depth https://www.conduktor.io/blog/beyond-limits-produce-large-records-without-undermining-apache-kafka/)

Answer (score 0):

Kafka shouldn't be used for transferring large binary blobs. Use systems like S3 (or Minio locally), and send URI values referring to the location of the files on shared disk storage... Then you can make your consumers download the files using that string rather than shove the binary file content in a Kafka record.

"Metadata" could then be brand new files (same filename, but with suffix `.meta`, for example) since S3 can be treated like a key-value blob store.